# EntityFramework create a new object and add existing objects to its navigation property

Tags: c#, navigation, entity-framework-5

I am newbie to Entity Framework 5. I try to search in the site, there are some similar questions but no answers.

I have an Announcement object and have navigation property Files

```
public partial class Announcement
    {
        //remove other properties

        public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    }
```

In sql server there is Announcement table， File table and an AnnouncementFiles table 
only has 2 fields [AnnouncementId] and [FileId].
The senario is: I create a new  Announcement ,but all files has already existing in database. 
Code is here:

```
public void CreateAnnouncement(Announcement announcement, List<Guid> fileIds)
        {
            using (var db = new MyDbEntities())
            {
                var files = db.Files.Where(f => fileIds.Contains(f.Id));
                db.Announcements.Add(announcement);
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    announcement.Files.Add(file);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

and there is error like (my .net framework is not English)
cannot update EntitySet“AnnouncementFiles”，because it has a DefiningQuery，but  do not have the operate to support currnet  element.

I cannot change the table structure, so is there any way to do this? some post says use **Attach** method but announcement.Files do not have this method.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the Linking table in your DbContext's `OnModelCreating` method.

You should look up defining many to many relationship in entity framework using FluentApi.  The code will look something like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Annoucement>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Files)
    .WithMany(x => x.Announcements)
    .Map(x => { 
      x.ToTable("AnnouncementFiles"; 
      x.MapLeftKey("AnnouncementID"); 
      x.MapRightKey("FileID"); 
    });
}
```

The rest of your code is fine.

Comment: I find the problem,that is I need to make both field as primary key in AnnouncementFiles, I dont know why, I do not change any code in my project. Is this the difference between EF5 and before versions?

Answer (score 0):

The fileIds.Contains(f.id) cannot be transformed into a sql query.  You can construct the expression tree using this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/

Comment: Actually EF4 and greater supports Contains().